# How can I get a reference to a Kotlin object by name?

Tags: reflection, kotlin

If I have a top level object declaration

```
package com.example

object MyObject {}
```

how can I convert the string `com.example.MyObject` into a reference to `MyObject`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have [`kotlin-reflect`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect) on the classpath then you can use the [`objectInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/object-instance.html) property of [`KClass`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/)

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val fqn = "com.example.MyObject"
    val clz: Class<*> = Class.forName(fqn)
    val instance = clz.kotlin.objectInstance
    println(instance) // com.example.MyObject@71623278
}
```

if you don't have `kotlin-reflect` then you can do it in a plain old java-way

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val fqn = "com.example.MyObject"
    val clz: Class<*> = Class.forName(fqn)
    val field: Field = clz.getDeclaredField("INSTANCE")
    val instance = field.get(null)
    println(instance) // com.example.MyObject@76ed5528
}
```

Comment: considering we use a function to return an object instance from its name, what is the return type please?

Comment: @fralbo `Any` would be the only reasonable return type in general (or `Any?` if you want to return `null` when there's no such `object`).

Answer (score 2):

you can using kotlin reflection, for example:

```
val it = Class.forName("com.example.MyObject").kotlin.objectInstance as MyObject;
```

Comment: If you can do `as MyObject`, you can write `MyObject` instead of all this in the first place :)

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov But what if the string represents subclass and `as MyObject` casts it to a base class. Anyway, you can throw out `as MyObject` and consider this example as a good one-liner.

Comment: "But what if the string represents subclass and `as MyObject` casts it to a base class" Doesn't apply to this question, where `MyObject` is an `object` which can't be extended. "you can throw out `as MyObject`" Yes, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Same a java code, you need use `Class.forName("com.example.MyObject")`. Now you have a Java class, but using `kotlin` extension, it convert to Kotlin class. `Class.forName("com.example.MyObject").kotlin`