# Kotlin get reference name of an object

Tags: kotlin, object-reference

How can I get the reference name of a Kotlin object? Say I have an object, how can I get, say, `com.myapp.CustomClass@6406`? My question is the reverse of [How can I get a reference to a Kotlin object by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647626/how-can-i-get-a-reference-to-a-kotlin-object-by-name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need combination of full object name and object [reference identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580984/how-do-you-get-the-object-reference-of-an-object-in-java-when-tostring-and-h).

So, code can be like this:

```
val myTestObject = ...
val referenceValue = Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(myTestObject))
val className = myTestObject.javaClass.canonicalName
val result = "$className@$referenceValue"
```

Comment: The hash code is different from the number printed out by debugger of that object

Comment: You need `Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(myTestObject))`, see http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java.